# Generic Query with Entity Framework 4. Generic Repository?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, generic-programming

This is my Database Structure : 
**Company**
CompanyID
CompanyName
...

**Location**
LocationID
LocationName
...

**Contact**
ContactID
ContactName
ContactEmail

**CompanyContact**
ContactID
CompanyID
IsActive

**LocationContact**
ContactID
LocationID
IsActive

Now I have a repository for each of these entity (CompanyContact, LocationContact)

```
public List<Contact> GetCompanyContact(int CompanyID)
{
   return _context.CompanyContacts.Where(p => p.CompanyID == CompanyID).Select(s => s.Contact).ToList();
}
...
public List<Contact> GetLocationContact(int LocationID)
{
   return _context.LocationContacts.Where(p => p.LocationID == LocationID).Select(s => s.Contact).ToList();
}
...
```

How Can I create a Generic method to get the List of contact. 
I would like to pass, the EntityName(CompanyContact or LocationContact) with the Reference Column name(CompanyID, LocationID).
Example of What I want :

```
public List<Contact> GetContact(string EntityName,String ColName){....}
Ex of call .
GetContact("CompanyContact","CompanyID");
```

Thx a lot.

**EDIT**
A Company can have Many Contact and a Location can have many contact too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you have your database context in your Repository, so I would use a little bit of generics with a dash of lambda to get something neat, like so:

```
public class MyRepository {
    var _context = new MyEFDatabaseEntities();

    public List<T> GetListOf<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        where T : class {

        return _context.CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(expression).ToList();
    }
}
```

This little one-liner lets you do fun stuff like this:

```
// first make a repository object
var repository = new MyRepository();

// now I can grab a list of contacts based on CompanyID
var contacts = repository.GetListOf<Contact>(c => c.ContactID == 12345);

// or I can get a list of contacts based on location
var contacts = repository.GetListOf<Contact>(c => c.LocationID == 12345);

// get all contacts for a company
var contacts = repository.GetListOf<CompanyContact>(c => c.CompanyID == 123).Contacts;

// get all confabs for a location
var contacts = repository.GetListOf<LocationContact>(c => c.CompanyID == 123).Contacts;
```

Comment: This dosen't work... I don't have the property (CompanyID or LocationID) In the expression c =>c.LocationID == 12345 or c=> c.CompanyID == 12345 .

Comment: Make sure you have a using statement for `System.Linq`

Comment: As long as your `Contact` class has the appropriate properties, this should work.  Make sure you're calling the `GetListOf` by passing the type of entity object you wish to return.

Comment: The only way I can make it work is  : var contacts = repository.GetListOf<Contact>(p => p.CompanyContacts.Any(pc => pc.ContactID == p.ContactID && pc.CompanyID == CompanyID));

Comment: I added a couple more examples to help you.  They should work.